# How do I install software from the Gnome Extensions Website?

Tags: gnome, extension

I have installed Gnome Addon, but when I go to the [Gnome Shell Extensions](https://extensions.gnome.org/), I still can't find any ON/OFF sliders.

Comment: Do you see the warning? *("We cannot detect a running copy of GNOME on this system, so some parts of the interface may be disabled")*

Comment: Yes, what desktop environment are you using?

Comment: What browser are you using? As observed on [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/125526/68678), Chrome/ium doesn't recognize Gnome Shell because of lack of NPAPI plugin support. You need to access the website on Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to install Gnome-Shell which can be done either, by using Ubuntu Software Center and searching for **GNOME Shell** or by using Terminal and the proper `apt-get install..` commands, depending on your OS and version number.

Example for [Ubuntu 11.10](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/easily-install-gnome-shell-ubuntu-1110-newer-linux/)
Example for [Ubuntu 12.10](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/10/how-to-get-complete-gnome-3-desktop-in.html)
Example for [Ubuntu 13.04](http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-gnome-3-8-2-and-extensions-on-ubuntu-13-04/)

Also of interest might be the [Gnome Wiki](https://wiki.gnome.org/GnomeShell)

Secondly you can download a program, called **Advanced Settings** (Tweak advanced Gnome3 settings), using Ubuntu Software Center again, which is very helpful as well to choose a gnome-shell theme, window and icon theme, manage fonts and font size and gnome-extensions.

It is also very helpful, like in the response-comments stated above, that you edit your question and add the following information:

- Ubuntu version
- Gnome Desktop Environment installed/or not

---

**Source:** *Gnome Shell Extensions Homepage* > [About](https://extensions.gnome.org/about/)

**I'm using GNOME 3. Why can't I install extensions?**

If you are using GNOME 3.4 or newer and installation still doesn't work, check to make sure that the "GNOME Shell Integration" plugin is installed and enabled in your browser preferences. Some browsers have a feature, click-to-play, which make it so the plugin cannot start without user intervention. Make sure that either http://extensions.gnome.org is whitelisted for the click-to-play feature, or click-to-play is turned off entirely. Check your browser's help for more details.

If you are behind a proxy, make sure you have configured your proxy in both your browser's configuration dialog as well as GNOME's Network panel under System Settings. GNOME Shell Extensions needs both settings panels configured for the one-click installation to work.

Some distributions don't quite package GNOME correctly. Make sure that you have the unzip package installed.

If you have checked all of these solutions and are still having trouble installing extensions, please file a bug report using the link in the footer of the page, giving your GNOME version, distribution and version, what solutions you have already tried, as well as what the Looking Glass says in both the Extensions and Errors tabs. It's also helpful to have a copy of the `~/.xsession-errors` file from the session that you installed extensions from.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced a similar issue on CentOS, this post ranks high in search results so I thought I should share what I learned. I was getting this error because the plugin package was not installed. Installing it with Yum immediately fixed the problem, although you have to use Firefox because Chrome doesn't support the protocol they are using.

```
sudo yum install gnome-shell-browser-plugin
```

Comment: `sudo yum install`  is for fedora, `sudo apt-get install` for ubuntu.

Comment: also works on Centos 7 but you should restart your browser after installation :)